# When importing a dependency script acts as it is in a different directory

Tags: python, import

I have the following directory:

project
|
├──folder1
│  └── text_to_use.txt
│  └── file.py
|
├──folder2
|  └──file_to_import.py
|
└──more_files.py

`file.py` is using `text_to_use.txt` and usually works fine.
When importing `file_to_import.py`, `file.py` starts acting as if inside `project` instead of `folder1`.

`file.py` code:

```
from folder2.file_to_import import some_class
open("text_to_use.txt", 'r')
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text_to_use.txt'
```

note:
I'm using PyCharm. this also happens when I import the same dependency with other files in folder1.

I'm looking for an elegant solution, not something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('folder2.file_to_import')
```

Comment: That `open()` call uses a plain filename with no path, so it will always look in the current directory.  As a debugging step, you can print the result of `os.getcwd()` to see the current directory.  (Does `file_to_import.py` change the current directory?)

Comment: @JohnGordon you are correct. I tried calling ```os.getcwd()``` with and without ```file_to_import.py``` and I saw that the directory has changed.
What does it mean? Can you help me solve my problem with this information?

Comment: So it sounds like `file_to_import.py` has an `os.chdir()` call at the top level.

Comment: dosn't happen to me

Comment: Does it mean I need to call ```os.chdir()``` in my ```file.py``` to change the working directory again?

Comment: If you do that, then presumably some code in `file_to_import` will break, because it had a reason for changing the directory...

Comment: Then how can I fix my problem? What do you suggest?

Comment: It would be best if you don't change the current directory at all, and just use full paths to open any necessary files, instead of depending on those files being in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

#### file.py

```
from pathlib import Path

pa_to_use = Path(__file__).parent.parent / "folder2" / "text_to_use.txt"

with pa_to_use.open() as f_use:
  stuff = f_use.read()
```